# Meaning of "android.enableAapt2 will be removed at the end of 2018"?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Gradle version: 4.4
Android Plugin Version: 3.1.2

Hi.
I'm working on an Android which should be deploy by using a Mobile Device Management called AirWatch.
So since Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0, even if I update application version code and version name, **the MDM thinks that the last deployed version and the current one are the same**.

Using dump badging command, I see that the **platformBuildVersionName is empty**. So when I disable aapt2 from my gradle properties file, **platformBuildVersionName is filled**. which allow me to deploy on the MDM. The problem is not up to date we don't when they will. So this is the work around I found. I know that the option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.

My question is what's the meaning "It will be removed at the end of 2018"? Is that mean, at the end of 2018, my app will not compile anymore?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue with platformBuildVersionName missing has been fixed recently in AAPT2. 
AAPT2 it is now released it in GMaven for faster releases (so you need to have the google() dependency in your build.gradle file), so please try with android gradle plugin 3.2.0 alpha16 or newer which may already contain it. If that still doesn't work, keep an eye out for new versions, it should be released shortly (if it hasn't been yet).
As for the information about AAPT1 deprecation - it means that at some point in the near future, near the end of 2018, there will be a release of Android Gradle Plugin that removes the `android.enableAapt2=false` flag. AAPT1 will be completely removed then so the hacks with disabling AAPT2 won't work anymore. If you run into any other issues with AAPT2 please file them on issue tracker, so that the team can fix them before everyone will need to move away from AAPT1.

Comment: Thanks so much. ".. will be removed at the end of 2018" is clear now.

Comment: @13KZ Did you try building with the newest 3.2.0-alpha16?

Comment: yes I tried 3.2.0-alpha16. When I use aapt available in 28.0.0-rc2 folder, I noticed that platformBuildVersionName just gone (This is the command : aapt dump badging MyApp.apk). Maybe I should not use aapt anymore.

Comment: Hmm it's possible the fix didn't get in yet, it was a valid bug so I wouldn't dismiss it so easily. Wait til alpha 17 is out and try again (should be out in a few days)

Comment: Yes I will. Thanks @Izabela

Comment: Np, please let me know if this is still an issue in alpha17 or alpha18

Comment: I tried to deploy my Apk using alph16 and the MDM is now able to retrieve necessary information and to make the deployment. SO I confirm that alpha16 fix aapt2 issue.

Comment: `'android.enableAapt2'` is deprecated now. Do we have any other method to use than this?

Comment: @RakeshKumar what do you mean, other method? You just need to figure out what the problem is with your code and fix it. If you file a new question on SO I can try to help you sort it out. But AAPT2 is now on and you should not disable it (starting 3.3 the flag is removed completely).

Comment: @lzabela Orlowska, I have used `android.enableAapt2` and it's working. But giving warning `deprecated now`.

Comment: @RakeshKumar yes, because it will be removed in 3.3. You should try to fix your project, disabling aapt2 is not a good solution.

Comment: @lzabela Orlowska Yes, that's what exactly I was meant to say. Thanks anyways. :)

Answer (score 12):

In 2019 New update
From Gradle.properties remove

`android.enableAapt2=false` this line

it will work now.

Answer (score -2):

1.Projenin gradle.properties:

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

2.File-> settings-Build, Execution > Instant run

```
unselected all options and rebuild projects
```

[image]

Comment: android.enableAapt2=false is deprecated.